# How to hide address bar in mobile web app?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a mobile web app (not native), and I want to use the complete screen height for my application. The problem is that the address bar of the browser takes up a lot of space, leaving me with about 4/5 of the entire screen.

I've made my app so that there's never any scrolling, the site always fits the height of the user's screen. What I'm really after, is what the facebook mobile website does. It scrolls down to hide the address bar.

Is there any universal way of doing this, for Android devices as well as Iphone, and in different mobile browsers (different address bar sizes)?

BTW: I'm using Iscroll4 to get a fixed footer and header.

**EDIT: This is the code I ended up with. I added two button to let the user choose whether or not to use fullscreen mode. This code works in combination with Iscroll4 and Jquery.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fullscreen = false;

    if(fullscreen==false)
    {
        window.removeEventListener("orientationchange", function(){ hideAddressBar(); } );
        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(){ showAddressBar(); } );
    }
    else
    {
        window.removeEventListener("orientationchange", function(){ showAddressBar(); } );
        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(){ hideAddressBar(); } );
    }

    $('#fullscreen').click(function(){
       hideAddressBar();
       fullscreen = true;
    });
    $('#normalscreen').click(function(){
       showAddressBar();
       fullscreen = false;
    });

});
function hideAddressBar()
{
    document.body.style.height = (window.outerHeight + 20) + 'px';
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
}
function showAddressBar()
{
    document.body.style.height = (window.outerHeight - 20) + 'px';
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a good article on how this is achieved here http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/remove-address-bar/

**Sample script**

```
function hideAddressBar()
{
  if(!window.location.hash)
  {
      if(document.height < window.outerHeight)
      {
          document.body.style.height = (window.outerHeight + 50) + 'px';
      }

      setTimeout( function(){ window.scrollTo(0, 1); }, 50 );
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){ if(!window.pageYOffset){ hideAddressBar(); } } );
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", hideAddressBar );
```

Answer (score 2):

The "scroll down" javascript trick should work on both iPhone and Android:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/remove-address-bar/

Not sure about other mobile browsers though sorry. Are you talking about Blackberry, Windows phone, etc. or more basic phones?

Comment: On Android (and Iphone?), you can download any browserapp you want, and use it as default. And all those browsers have different heights for their adress bars. I'm mostly targetting Android and Iphone users, not so much BlackBerry or Windows Phone. Great link btw !

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually do this is:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
  }, 0);
});
```

But it will only work if the page is long enough to scroll down a bit.

Comment: Yeah, I've found that solution online as well, it just doesn't fit my needs, since my app won't have any scrolling.

Comment: Actually I found this post rather helpful, so ignore my previous comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

For android:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)){
    window.scrollTo(0,1);
 }
```

For iPhone:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

Comment: Isn't the one for Iphone only available for native Iphone apps?

Comment: Absolutely no, its an meta tag. Have a look at this http://www.luscarpa.com/development/make-your-website-an-iphone-web-application/

Comment: `window.scrollTo(0,1);` doesn't work on my Android device. The if statement returns true though.

Comment: I came to know that you are using iScroll plugin, so it wont work.

Comment: Will your javascript hide the adress bar, or just scroll down? If it does scroll down, I might be better off using Jquery than Iscroll.

Comment: I just found out that the Iphone user needs to add my website to his homescreen and launch it from there, in order for `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
` to work